# When can I re-apply for the UK Visa after OVERSTAYING for 2 months?

Tags: visas, uk, overstaying

I have applied twice for tourist visa but got refusals. Second time I received a  letter saying "when I was still in the UK I should have received a notification about my overstay" (I never did) and HO were not sure if I would leave the UK after my visitor visa expires this time. When can I apply for other Visa again? Should it be 1 year after I came back to my home country?

Comment: Unclear. You can reapply as soon as you receive your passport back om mail  with a new refusal in it. Or any time you have a passport and the fee. Do you mean to ask when you can apply successfully?

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't receive a ban for certain period of time, you can reapply the same day.

The thing is that you'll almost certainly get another refusal unless you provide UK consulate with a good reason to visit the UK and good proofs you won't overstay this time.